# How does interacting with the django rest api through the url work?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I get that the Django rest framework is for interacting with the Django server programmatically but one thing I still don't understand is how.
what i want to do is have my client app (mobile app) send data (somehow) to the Django server in order to create/retrieve data based on variables and obviously this has to be done through the URL since there will be no direct GUI interaction with the API. (unless I'm mistaken, which I probably am)
 I have gone through the official documentation and followed the tutorial to the end and still don't understand how this is supposed to work.
all I ask for is a quick and simple explanation because I have searched everywhere and haven't found a simple enough explanation to grasp the core concept of how this is all supposed to work.

Comment: You send a HTTP request, just like your browser does. In fact most browsers can even visualize the response quite nicely. For example: https://api.stackexchange.com//2.2/users/9317843?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow

Comment: ok but I also want to be able to, for example, create users and other models and don't know how I'm supposed to specify the data for each field in said models.

Comment: typically you pass these as POST parameters. In fact a REST API is not much different than a how a browser interacts with a browser. The only important difference is that for webpages, one writes the data in some (nice formatted) HTML stream, whereas an API typically uses a less *noisy* and standardized format.

Comment: yes, and that is what I don't know how to do. when looking through the documentation i figured it had something to do with these POST and GET and other parameters and the answer was probably staring me in the face but i just couldn't figure out how to use them

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [JSONResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) and related objects:

This will allow you to send JSON in response to a request.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def my_view_json(request):    
    response = JsonResponse({'foo': 'bar'})
    return response
```

If your templates or webpages need to make a request *to* a view and specify different parameters, they can do so by adding POST variables [(examples)](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp). These can be parsed in the view like so:

```
def myView(request):
    my_post_var = request.POST.get('variable_name', 'default_value')
    my_get_var = request.GET.get('variable_name', 'default_value')
```

You can then parse what was sent any way you like and decide what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically,
You define the URLS upon which you perform Get/POST/PUT Requests and You can Send Data to that.

Eg:
urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import url,include
    from app import views
urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^(?i)customertype/$',views.CustomerViewSet.as_view()),
 url(r'^(?i)profile/$', views.Save_Customer_Profile.as_view()),
 url(r'^(?i)customer_image/$', views.Save_Customer_Image.as_view()),
]
```

Now Whenever User would send a Request to:
example.com/profile ==> This would be received in the Save_Customer_Profile View based on the Method Type, Save_Customer_Profile is as follows:

```
class Save_Customer_Profile(APIView):
    """Saves and Updates User Profile!"""
    def get(self, request, format=None):
       return AllImports.Response({"Request":"Method Type is GET Request"})

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        return AllImports.Response({"Request":"Method Type is Post Request"})

    def put(self,request, format=None):
        return AllImports.Response({"Request":"Method Type is Put Request"})
```

Comment: Consider a Rest API as writing the Full Backend of a Web/Android/Ios Application with no Front-end as you explicitly have to call the API!

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP was referring to how to do GET/POST request programmatically. In that case, it is enough to do (values are dummy):

GET:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/snippets/')

print(r.json())
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

POST:

```
data = {'code': 'print(" HELLO !!!")', 'language': 'java','owner': 'testuser'}
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/snippets/', data=data,  auth=('testuser', 'test'))
```